# Stub files are not included in the distribution despite py.typed marker included in the package

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils, type-hinting

I've [contributed](https://github.com/rominf/ordered-set) stub file to [ordered-set](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set) library. To include stub files I [followed](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set/pull/42/commits/429ddf1f0297590cdb286cf700cff17dec33fecb) recommendations from [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installed_packages.html#making-pep-561-compatible-packages) and [PEP-561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/). But when I do `python setup.py sdist` I get distribution without `ordered_set.pyi` file:

```
$ tar -tvf dist/ordered-set-*.tar.gz --wildcards '*pyi'
tar: *pyi: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Also, where is the code, related to stub files inclusion, in the `distutils` library? I've [searched](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=%22py.typed%22&unscoped_q=%22py.typed%22) for it to try to debug my problem, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robyn Speer (the author of `ordered-set` library) has found the answer:

> Oh, I figured it out. `py.typed` is something that's supposed to go in the package, and technically, `ordered_set` doesn't have any packages. It has a module.
>
> In PEP 561, I found: "This PEP does not support distributing typing information as part of module-only distributions. The code should be refactored into a package-based distribution and indicate that the package supports typing as described above."